# EclipseLink: ManyToOne mapping to SINGLE_TABLE inheritance strategy fails

Tags: sql-server-2008, jpa, eclipselink

I'm working in migrating a Kodo JDO project to EclipseLink and stuck while trying to map SINGLE_TABLE inheritance entity to another entity. I get "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Audit' to data type int" and no clue how to fix this.

1. How to map/join single table inheritance to another entity?
2. How to get a collection of single table inheritance subclass

Please help.

This is how my database looks:

- Audit Table: Holds audit information regarding user.

  - Audit_id is PK key and has a discriminator column.
  - If discriminator value of type int. 1 for Address details and 2 for Phone details.
  - One user can have more than one audit records. So I need to fetch a collection.
- User Table -> user_id is PK.

  - Column stores audit id instead of string. The audit id points to most recent change.

User id 100 has 2 audit rows for phone number. I couldn't get collection of results. 
[Database - Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Uh9.png)

**Base Class:**

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@Table(name = "audit")
@NamedQuery(name = "Audit.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM Audit m")
public  class Audit implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  @Column(name = "audit_id")
  private int auditId;

  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private int userId;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "addressAudit1")
  private List<User> User;

  //Getters and Setters are defined.
}
```

**SubClass 1:**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Address extends Audit
{
  @Column(name = "street_addr1")
  private String streetAddr1;

  @Column(name = "street_addr2")
  private String streetAddr2;

  //Getters and Setters are defined.
}
```

**SubClass 2:**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class Phone extends Audit
{
  @Column(name = "home_phone")
  private String homePhone;

  @Column(name = "home_phone_ext")
  private String homePhoneExt;

  @Column(name = "work_phone")
  private String workPhone;

  @Column(name = "work_phone_ext")
  private String workPhoneExt;

  //Getters and Setters are defined.
}
```

**User Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT m FROM User m")
public class User implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private int UserId;

*//Below code is causing issue*
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "CURRENT_STREET")
  private Audit addressAudit1;

  //Getters and Setters are defined.
}
```

**UseCase**
1. I need to search an user based on ID. Here is how I search

```
public static User getUserForId(long userID, EntityManagerFactory emf) throws Exception
  {
    User user = null;
    EntityManager em = null;
    try
    {
      em = emf.createEntityManager();
      TypedQuery<User> q = em.createQuery("select u from " + User.class.getName() + " u where u.userId = :userIndex", User.class);
      q.setParameter("userIndex", userID);
      List<User> userList = q.getResultList();
      if (userList.size() > 0)
      {
        Iterator<User> userItr = userList.iterator();
        if (userItr.hasNext())
        {
          user = userItr.next();
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      logger.error(e.getMessage());
      throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
      em.close();
    }
    return user;
  }
```

Exception is thrown at q.getResultList().

```
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Audit' to data type int.
Error Code: 245
Call: SELECT audit_id, type, JDOVERSION, user_id FROM audit WHERE ((audit_id = ?) AND (type = ?))
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="addressAudit1" referenceClass=Audit )
```

NOTE: The same works when I use @embedded and @embeddable annotations.I gave up on it because, I'm unable to fetch collection of audits.

Comment: What happens if  you change the target type to the concrete class? `private Audit addressAudit1`; > `private Address addressAudit1`;

Comment: @AlanHay,This is the exception I get.Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7250] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationExceptionException Description: [class com.test.User] uses a non-entity [class com.test.Address] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field addressAudit1].  Though Address class is marked with @ Entity, why does it say as non-entity ?

Comment: I tried to use @ VariableOneToOne on User class right before @ JoinColumn(name = "CURRENT_STREET"). I also removed Discriminator column and values from Audit, Address and Phone class. Now I get  Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'DTYPE'. So it didn't consider @ VariableOneToOne. Do you think if Discriminator column definition in entity is causing this issue? Should I go back to @ embeddable ? If so, is there a way to get list of addresses and phones ?

Comment: Your mapping doesn't match up with the description.  "User id 100 has 2 audit rows for phone number" to me means that a User has two audit rows, but your mapping has it such that a User has one Audit while an audit has many users. JoinColumn(name = "CURRENT_STREET") means that the current street field in the User table is a foreign key to the Audit table ID - an int in this case. The error you mention I suspect is because the Audit classes are not entities in the persistence unit in the environment you are using - you might need to clean up and verify what you have been deploying.

Comment: I suggest you start small - get it working with just User-Audit before you start adding Audit subclasses into the mix, as the issue(s) doesn't seem related to inheritance

Comment: Sure, I will try as you mentioned and update here. Thanks for suggestion @Chris